# Java Regex Matcher Problem with dynamic Strings

Tags: java, regex, string-formatting

I have some problems with Regex in Java and dynamic input - No problems with Regex at all ;)

```
private static Pattern START_SUITE = Pattern.compile("Test Suite '(\\S+)'.*started at\\s+(.*)");

String line = "Test Suite '/a/long/path/to/some/file.octest(Tests)' started at 2011-07-09 08:01:34 +0000";

Matcher m = START_SUITE.matcher(line);

if (m.matches) {
    //do something
}
```

This works fine with my test java application with the string above.
But when the String does come from an other source Matcher doesn't match it.

```
processHandler.addProcessListener(new ProcessAdapter() {
 @Override
 public void onTextAvailable(final ProcessEvent event, final Key outputType) {
 try {
   outputParser.myMatchStringFunction(event.getText());
 }
 ...
}

 public void myMatchStringFunction(String line) {
  Matcher m = START_SUITE.matcher(line);
  if (m.matches) {
  ...
```

I checked the String with printing and it looks ok.

Any ideas what could happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for that hint.

Adding DOTALL and (.*) at the end of every pattern solved the problem

```
private static Pattern START_SUITE = Pattern.compile("Test Suite '(\\S+)'.*started at\\s+(.*)", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Answer (score 3):

Whether the string came from a string literal or dynamically from input won't affect anything at all. So it's either something wrong with your regular expression, or something in your input that you weren't expecting and need to trim off.

You say you've printed the string - but it's easy to miss non-printable characters, or newlines etc.

I suggest you print a sample failing string out in full, including the Unicode character values, e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
{
    char c = text.charAt(i);
    System.out.println("Position: " + i + "Character: " + c
                       + " Unicode: " + (int) c);
}
```

Then you'll be able to put *exactly* that string into your code if you need to, and you'll probably be able to spot what's wrong just by inspecting it in that form.